# Multiple web-interfaces for same neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

Note: I want solutions only for neo4j community edition, not the enterprise one. Thanks!

I want to use the default web interface http://localhost:7474/browser/ for development and read/write purposes Also, I would like to use another web interface which I will apparently open to public for read purposes, which may go by certain different port say, 8474.

I tried this:

```
- Used two instances(neo4j folders) - a) read_only = true b) read_only commented out.
- Changed http/https ports for the both to differentiate.
- Changed org.neo4j.server.database.location property in 'read_only' one to point to the location of 'read/write' one.
```

This doesn't work. Any workaround? I just want two web-interfaces for the same database. One read only. One read/write supported.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a cluster of 3 Neo4j enterprise instances (or 2 instances plus one arbiter) and set `read_only=true` on one of the instances.

See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html for detailed setup instructions.

Comment: But this will only work for enterprise edition, not the community edition.

Comment: That's true. But you didn't ask for community-only solutions ;-)

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks anyways for your time :)